# What is the maximum number of threads that can be running in a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi-7

In a Delphi application, what is the maximum number of concurrent threads that can be running at one time ? Suppose that a single thread processing time is about 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of concurrent threads is limited by available resources.  However, keep in mind that every thread uses a minimum amount of memory (usually 1MB by default, unless you specify differently), and the more threads you run, the more work the OS has to do to manage them, and the more time it takes just to keep switching between them so they have fair opportunity to run.  A good rule of thumb is to not have more threads than there are CPUs available, since that will be the maximum number of threads that can physically run at any given moment.  But you can certainly have more threads than CPUs, the OS will simply schedule them accordingly, which can degrade performance if you have too many running at a time.  So you need to think about why you are using threads in the first place and plan accordingly to trade off between performance, memory usage, overhead, etc.  Multi-threaded programming is not trivial, so do not treat it lightly.

Comment: Then if we are 64 bit application, will the performance of the application will be different.?

Comment: You will have access to more memory, and can create more threads, which means more memory used, more time managing the threads, etc. So you still have to watch your resource usage and balance it for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

This is memory dependent, there is no fixed limit to how many threads or other objects that you can create.  At some point, if you allocate too much memory, you may get an "out of memory" exception, so you should think about how many threads you really need to invoke and go from there.  Also keep in mind the more threads that you invoke, you should expect the processing time for all of the threads to decrease.  So you may not get the performance that you're looking for if you have too many concurrent threads at once.  I hope that this helps!